# encountered error while building tensorflow in terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, repository, bazel

when i go for building the tensorflow in terminal via command

/tensorflow$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

error occurs as follows

/tensorflow.bzl:449:21: name 'set' is not defined

ERROR: error loading package '': Extension 'tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl' has errors
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension 'tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl' has error